# Error: Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was detected

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, nokia, lumia

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8. I have got three Windows Phone devices, lumia 620, 920, 1320 and these are all developer unlocked devices. The 620 device has got Windows Phone 8.1 preview installed. Whenever I'm trying to deploy a WP8 project to this 620, debug windows gives me this error:

> 1>Deployment of application to device failed.
>   1>Error: Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I have tried deploying after rebooting the phone, VS 2013 and even my PC, but failed in every case.

Please share any idea what may have caused this issue to occur or help me on how can I solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @har07, 620 is WP8 device, why should I be using Zune to detect it?
Plus, my PC is detecting and showing up the device in file explorer every time I am connecting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @aloisdg said in a comment, you can fix the problem by unplugging your phone, going to 'Control Panel->Hardware and Sound->Devices, removing your phone, then connecting your phone by USB.

Answer (score 2):

So before you deploy the app to the device, check whether the device is being recognized in your pc/laptop.

Try connecting your device from another port. Did you try with another cable for the device.

Have a look over [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/314a50ee-ac0e-4c78-8c8d-c81092fd362b/no-windows-phone-8-detected) thread for more.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b54277c0-84aa-433c-ba60-ebc536ccd4e4/vs2102-deployment-failed-because-no-windows-phone-8-phone-was-detected?forum=wpsubmit

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried all these and as I mentioned earlier, my PC is recognizing my phone. No luck on that thread.

Comment: Did you developer unlock your device?

Comment: Great answer. In my case I just had to take it out of the USB slot and put it back in. This seems to be a weird bug in VS2013?

Comment: Disconnect the Phone from the USB. Then go to 'Control Panel->Hardware and Sound->Devices' and Remove your phone. Then connect the Phone to the USB. This solution works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Problem Might be with the driver of any port . I also faced it , solved it with the following steps.

1. Check All the ports of your laptop/PC.
2. Go to Device Manager-->Universal Serial Bus Controller-->Uninstall the one which is having yellow mark.
3. Go to Action-->Scan for hardware changes . Driver will automatically get installed.
4. Then Run Your App :)